# Dialog does not appear when I try to show it in AsynchTask in onPreExecute

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am trying to display a dialog to the user when I invoke an AsynchTask.

I am trying to use the onPreExecute method like this:

```
     protected void onPreExecute(Long result) 
     {
         dialog = new Dialog(UpdateProfileActivity.this);

         dialog.setContentView(R.layout.please_wait);
         dialog.setTitle("Updating account details...");

         dialog.show();      
     }
```

and then in onPostExecute method do this:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
    {    
        try {
            dialog.dismiss();
        } catch (Exception ee) {
            // nothing
        }
```

But the dialog does not show up. I looked at the documentation and even though there are mentions of onPreExecute, I am not sure how it is used.  Mine is simply never called.

What is the proper use of it and how do I make sure the dialogs are properly opened and closed?

Thank you!

Comment: Genadinik - again, do not put tags in subjects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `onPreExecute` method is never called, because you are not overriding it properly. 
The correct method signature should be:

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute(){
    //Your code
}
```

As a general tip, always use the `@Override` annotation when overriding methods. When you try to override a method that doesn't exist, or when you've typed something wrong, an error appears.

Comment: yes I saw that mistake of mine :) will accpt your answer as this site lets me :) Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Niek is right about the pre execute not being called.  However, it seems to me that what you probably want is ProgressDialog.  You can set it up like this

```
ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(context);
progress.setMessage("Loading Message");
progress.setTitle("Title");
progress.show();
```

Then, in onPostExecute, you will call

```
progress.dismiss();
```

To remove it.  If you need something that looks more custom, you can subclass progress dialog to add a custom image/ other customizations.

Comment: @James what is the main difference beteen the Dialog that I use and ProgressDialog? I don't really have a progress bar. All I am doing is displaying text saying "please wait"

Comment: ProgressDialogs are used in cases where you want to show the user some sort of progress.  It can be either indeterminate (usually the case for calling asynchronous network calls where you don't know how long they will take) or you can show a progress bar.  Dialogs are a more general type, of which progress is subclassed.  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Comment: Also, in eclipse, try using the @Override before methods like neik showed, so that eclipse will tell you if you are not overriding it correctly